# Find all nonnegative integers $m$ and $n$ such that $m!+1=n^2$.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, factorial

This question is inspired by [Subgroup of Order $n^2-1$ in Symmetric Group $S_n$ when $n=5, 11, 71$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1854953/subgroup-of-order-n2-1-in-symmetric-group-s-n-when-n-5-11-71).

> Find all nonnegative integers $m$ and $n$ such that $m!+1=n^2$.

We know that $(m,n)=(4,5)$, $(m,n)=(5,11)$, and $(m,n)=(7,71)$ are solutions.  Are there more solutions?  Are there only finitely solutions?

Comment: This is open.  Known as [Brocard's Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brocard%27s_problem)

Comment: Thank you very much for the reference.

Comment: I have given a proof  in :
http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1892315/179940

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see other solutions here:

https://oeis.org/A025494

But for proving it is infinity there isn't any sloutions the problem is open.

See:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brocard%27s_problem